# Rounding a float to one decimal place then convert to a string

Tags: c++, rounding, tostring, floating-accuracy

I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 

std::string ExampleInstance::RoundNumber(float result) {

    std::string RoundResult;

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    RoundResult = std::to_string(result);
    return RoundResult;
}
```

I want to pass this method a float, round it to one decimal place, convert it to a string and then return it. Currently this doesn't do anything to the number.

Would `setPrecision` be more effective? I'm new to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/) for this purpose. Not forget to include `<sstream>`.

**Code snippet:**

```
string RoundNumber(float result)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out<<std::setprecision(1)<<std::fixed<<std::showpoint<< result;
    std::string RoundResult =  out.str();
    return RoundResult;
}
```